# How to get a variable from another GUI class?

Tags: javascript, java, mysql

I'm trying to access data from a text field in another class. 
currently, it's like this.

```
public class Search(){
String txtfield = "Something";
 }
public class GetSomething(){
String name;
Search s = new Search();

name = s.txtfield();
```

I've tried multiple ways to try and do this but none has proved to be useful or just work.
Please leave me some solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided an access modifier for the txtfield variable. A class-variable without access modifier is automatically made package-protected, meaning it can be accessed only from within the class itself and classes within the same package. Either make a package that contains both Search and GetSomething or change the scope of the txtfield variable. Additionally, when you add () after the variable name, you're saying that you want to call the method txtfield. There is no such method. When accessing class-variables, you just need to provide the name of the variable.